# Can't deserialize Zoho Docs API response

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, zoho

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong with trying to deserialize this Zoho Docs API response?

I have a folder structure with "My Folders" as the root and then "TestFolder" inside of that. This is the JSON response I get back from the Zoho Docs API:

```
[
    {
        "FOLDER_NAME": "My Folders",
        "SUCCESS": "1",
        "SCOPE": "0"
    },
    [
        {
            "AUTHOR_ID": "123456",
            "FOLDER_ID": "xxx",
            "PARENT_FOLDER_ID": "1",
            "FOLDER_NAME": "TestFolder",
            "LAST_MODIFIED_TIME": "1435875889219",
            "ENCFOLDER_NAME": "TestFolder",
            "SCOPE": "0",
            "AUTHOR_NAME": "John Smith",
            "LAST_MODIFIEDBY": "123456",
            "IS_SHARED": true,
            "LAST_MODIFIED_AUTHOR_NAME": "John Smith"
       }
    ]
]
```

I've tried to deserialize the response into a Folder or List with this class, but I've had no luck:

```
    public class Folder
    {
        [JsonProperty("FOLDER_NAME")]
        public string FolderName { get; set; }
    }
```

Whether I try to deserialize this into just the object or a list of Folder I get this error from Json.NET:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'ZohoModels.Folder' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. The root container is an array not an object so needs to be deserialized into a collection, say `List<Folder>`.
2. The array contains two entries: a JSON object and nested JSON array.  The [documentation](https://www.zoho.com/docs/zoho-docs-api.html) is vague, but it looks like these folders are recursive, and an array of folders will contain pairs of folder/child folder array containers.  Since Json.NET decides whether to serialize a POCO based on whether or not it implements `IEnumerable`, there is no single class that can be deserialized from both a JSON array and a JSON object.  Thus it will be necessary to create a custom JSON converter for a `List<Folder>` to skip through the array and match up the folders with their arrays of children.

The following classes and converter should do the job:

```
public class Folder
{
    public Folder() { this.Folders = new List<Folder>(); }

    [JsonProperty("FOLDER_NAME")]
    public string FolderName { get; set; }

    public List<Folder> Folders { get; set; }
}

public class FolderListConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(List<Folder>);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        // Format of a folder list is
        // Object with name of folder
        // Array of child folders as a folderlist.
        var folders = (existingValue as List<Folder> ?? new List<Folder>());
        var array = JArray.Load(reader);
        foreach (var token in array)
        {
            switch (token.Type)
            {
                case JTokenType.Object:
                    folders.Add(token.ToObject<Folder>(serializer));
                    break;
                case JTokenType.Array:
                    {
                        var folder = folders.Last(); // Throws an exception if none read yet.
                        (folder.Folders = (folder.Folders ?? new List<Folder>())).AddRange(token.ToObject<List<Folder>>(serializer));
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new JsonSerializationException("unknown token " + token.ToString());
            }
        }
        return folders;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; }}

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And use it like:

```
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { Converters = new JsonConverter[] { new FolderListConverter() } };
        var folders = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Folder>>(json, settings);
```